# I'm struggling to start to use typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my project structure.

```
/public
  /js
    const.js
    const.js.map
    index.js
    index.js.map
  index.html
/src
  const.ts
  index.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

***index.ts***

```
import * as Const from './const'

const label = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("#label")
label!.innerHTML = Const.default
```

***const.ts***

```
const message = "Hi"

export default message
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es5","DOM"
    ],             
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./public/js",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

When I set the module as "commonjs" I've got this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
> at index.js:21

And if I set as "es6" I've got this.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I'm really confusing. I'd searched about these error in web and StackOverflow, But most reply says just change the module, or use a webpack or babel.
But I don't want to use pre-compiler.

How can I solve this problem for my front-end dev?

Comment: Basically modern browsers are now supporting native `esm` module which means you code can run if you target module from `es2015`, then add script tag with your entry point `<script  type="module" src="./js/index.js" />`

Comment: Thank you! I set the target to "es2015", and loaded the index.js file with "module" attribute. In the first time I've got faced this error 
`GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/public/js/const net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`
But, I changed the module name of "./const" to "./const.js" and it really worked.

I don't want to really care about old browser with es5 as low-level support. So, es6 would be perfect for my browser. And all file bundle seems not good to my project, because I'm not making Single Page Application. So, really thank you. You make me try this again and make work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a module bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to handle module resolution. There are many guides on how to use webpack with Typescript, including [one on official webpack website](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/).

Also on there is [this guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html) on Typescript official website which includes brief explanation on who to integrate with build tools like webpack, and other like Browserify, Duo, Gulp, Grunt, etc.

I recommend starting with webpack. It is simple to use for basic scenarios and have very power capabilities for advanced scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, appreciate. I will look for the webpack for further!

Comment: I used the way with webpack. and my doubt was solved perfectly after some trials. Really thanks. https://medium.com/@fredriccliver/typescript-and-webpack-tutorial-for-hater-of-those-3dda77789343